# simple html dom failed to get title server issue?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm using my simple html dom on my localhost, but after i transfer it to my server and test it. it displays failed to get title. Is there something wrong with my codes? I don't think it's my code because it's working on my localhost and inserting it to my database. but then on my server it doesn't work. The process of my PHP is to get URLs then use simple html dom to get the titles and then I will connect to my database then save the titles. After transferring these to my server and test it . it diplays  "failed to get title" then it doesn't save on the server's database. mysql.

```
$html = file_get_html($video_url);
if($html!=false)
{
   $title =  $html->find('title',0)->plaintext;
}
else
{
   echo "failed to get title";
}
```

Comment: can you show us your code ?

Comment: *Is there something wrong with my codes?* what codes?

Comment: can you try something like http://www.google.com for reference (instead of that video_url) ?

Comment: It could be that your server does not have permission to read the HTML from `$video_url`.

Comment: @etr i've tried it. but still it doesn't work

Comment: @AlexisWilke i've set my files to chmod 777

Comment: What is the URL? A local file or a remote file? Also file_get_html() is not a standard PHP function, so its definition could be quite important to your question.

Comment: @AlexisWilke i have tried google.com but it doesn't work .